# How to compile libusb as shared library?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld, autotools, libusb-1.0

I am trying to build libusb as shared library as follows.

Following are two steps. 1. Configure 2. Make.

I pass "--enable-shared" to configure script assuming it will generate the shared .so file

## Configure

```
./configure CC=/mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --host=arm-linux --enable-udev=no --enable-shared
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for arm-linux-gcc... /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... no
checking for arm-linux-dumpbin... no
checking for arm-linux-link... no
checking for dumpbin... no
checking for link... link -dump
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking the name lister (nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to arm-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for arm-linux-objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for arm-linux-dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for arm-linux-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for arm-linux-strip... strip
checking for arm-linux-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse nm output from /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for arm-linux-mt... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the /mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc linker (/mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for arm-linux-windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for inline... inline
checking operating system... Linux
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
checking asm/types.h usability... yes
checking asm/types.h presence... yes
checking for asm/types.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for linux/netlink.h... yes
checking for linux/filter.h... yes
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking sys/timerfd.h usability... yes
checking sys/timerfd.h presence... yes
checking for sys/timerfd.h... yes
checking whether TFD_NONBLOCK is declared... yes
checking whether to use timerfd for timing... yes
checking for struct timespec... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for syslog... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking signal.h usability... yes
checking signal.h presence... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating libusb-1.0.pc
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libusb/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/doxygen.cfg
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

## Make

```
make CC=/mnt/store/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/store/build-without-sdk/libusb-1.0.19'
Making all in libusb
make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/store/build-without-sdk/libusb-1.0.19/libusb'
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-core.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-descriptor.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-io.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-strerror.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-sync.lo
  CC       libusb_1_0_la-hotplug.lo
  CC       os/libusb_1_0_la-threads_posix.lo
  CC       os/libusb_1_0_la-linux_usbfs.lo
  CC       os/libusb_1_0_la-poll_posix.lo
  CC       os/libusb_1_0_la-linux_netlink.lo
  CCLD     libusb-1.0.la
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/store/build-without-    sdk/libusb-1.0.19/libusb'


Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/store/build-without-sdk/libusb-1.0.19/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/store/build-without-sdk/libusb-1.0.19/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/store/build-without-sdk/libusb-1.0.19'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/storebuild-without-sdk/libusb-1.0.19'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/store/build-without-sdk/libusb-1.0.19'
```

But I cant find libusb-1.0.so

Comment: could you add the output of make and configure to your question? Without, this is just guesswork.

Comment: Thanks; Hm, still mysterious; does `make clean; make` (omitting the explicit setting of the `CC` variable in the make call) help? If it doesn't I'm a bit out of ideas. The configure output states that config.h was unchanged; I've seen the most wonderful (read: horrible) things with autotools, so maybe starting off with a clean build directory would be a good idea.

Comment: Libtool usually has a `.libs` directory where it keeps shared objects and the final shared '.so' (and static) libraries. These are installed in the right place by `make install`, and use 'rpath' magic when, say, running a package's test suite without installing the library.

Comment: If that exists it would probably be at /mnt/store/build-without-    sdk/libusb-1.0.19/libusb/.libs/  Can OP confirm this?

Comment: @Qwertyzw Got it. That is where it is. Inside libusb/.libs/. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .so file is built in `libusb/.libs/`
Its not very obvious by looking at the build logs though.

Comment: This is fine - you can accept your own answer. Perhaps just add some [information](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Creating-object-files).

Comment: You must not use `LDFLAGS="-static"`. No `.so` will be created if you do.